# How can I change my current directory using tmpdir?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

How can I write the files to the `tmpdir` directory instead of the current directory? How can I use `tmpdir`. The documentation  didn't help me.

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:pytest] and indeed `tmpdir` is a pytest fixture. But your function doesn't look like a test. Can you provide more context?

Comment: With this function I created my files in the current directory. And I call my function within the test, but I think it is not important here.

Comment: Don't change your current working directory - it's bad practice and totally unreliable. Use absolute file path instead.

Comment: but If really I have to create that folder and move my files their with using tmpdir)

Answer (score 3):

pytest recommends the newer [`tmp_path` fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmp-path-fixture) over `tmpdir`. `tmp_path` uses [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib), so you can conveniently use `/` to define paths based on them.

Here is how you might use it in a test:

```py
def test_foo(tmp_path):
    make_file(tmp_path / "file1", "something")
```

If you *really* need to change to that directory, do something like

```py
def test_foo(tmp_path):
    os.chdir(tmp_path)  # If you're using Python 3.6 or later
    # or if you're on an older version:
    os.chdir(str(tmp_path))
```

but depending on the current directory is a code smell. Consider refactoring your code so it can run from anywhere.

Comment: There is a factory also available in the current version: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html